# Track referral when app is already installed

Tags: android, google-analytics, install-referrer

I have a play-store link generated by [url builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder). To track the referrer who referred my app, I have implemented campaign measurement as described in [official docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns). 
But if the app is already installed, I am not sure how to parse the url. According to official example:

```
// In this example, campaign information is set using
// a url string with Google Analytics campaign parameters.
// Note: This is for illustrative purposes. In most cases campaign
//       information would come from an incoming Intent.
   String campaignData = "http://examplepetstore.com/index.html?" +
   "utm_source=email&utm_medium=email_marketing&utm_campaign=summer" +
   "&utm_content=email_variation_1";
```

I am not sure how to read the url data into intent. Should I be using deeplink to parse my play-store URL?

Comment: You will receive a broadcast when the app is installed with all that data. If the app is already installed you have no way to check that

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the campaign parameters on a tracker provided by Google Analytics SDK v4 for Android:

Follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns)